# Writing different pieces of code to the compiled (.elc) file, based on different conditions

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I want to conditionally write different pieces of codes to the compiled version of my elisp files (.elc), I can do this with function definitions:

```
(defalias 'my-test
  (eval-when-compile
    (if nil 
      (lambda ()
        (message "True"))
      (lambda ()
        (message "False")))))
```

With the code above, I can assign different anonymous functions to `my-test` based on different conditions and the result will get written to the compiled `.elc` file. But what I want to write is **function calls** in **file scope**. like so:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (if nil
      (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.gitconfig\\'" . A-mode))
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.gitconfig\\'" . B-mode))))

;; or using `when' to either write a call or do nothing:
(eval-when-compile
  (when (not (eq (user-uid) 0))           ; if uid != 0
    (dangerous-call)))
```

The code gets evaluated in compile time and the results of evaluation will only be available in the compilation process and after that nothing goes to `.elc`, because I didn't assign it to anything, but how can I actually write the **byte-compiled** results of `if` control (which is a **call** to `add-to-list` function) to the compiled `.elc` file? in this case I wanted `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.gitconfig\\'" . B-mode))` to get written to the `.elc` file.

Comment: Emacs Lisp isn't quite my forte, but have you tried something like `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.gitconfig\\'" . (eval-when-compile (if nil 'a-mode 'b-mode))))`?

Comment: @jkiiski this should work, but if I use `when` instead of `if` and the condition turns out `false`, then there is nothing to return and ... . for example if I wanted to call a function *or* do nothing at all.

Comment: How about `(eval (eval-when-compile (if nil '(message "True") '(message "False"))))`? My quick test shows that it produces an .elc with only `(message "False")` in it.

Comment: @jkiiski in case of `add-to-list` what goes in is the value of `auto-mode-alist`!

Comment: Did you quote the call (`'(add-to-list ...)`)?

Comment: @jkiiski Sorry!, now it works, but is this byte-code? I mean it just copies whatever is in .el file. I get different results from these two: `(eval
 (eval-when-compile
   (if t
       '(defun f ()
          (interactive)))))` and `(defun f ()
  (interactive))`

Comment: You could use a macro like `(defmacro define-if (condition form) (if condition \`,form))`. It seems to produce the same bytecode with `(define-if t (defun f () (interactive)))`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot eval (and can't edit) from that. `(defmacro define-if (condition form) (if (eval condition) \`,form))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to this is macros: if you write a macro which expands to the code you want, then simply place an invocation of the macro at top-level, then the expansion of the macro will end up in the compiled file.

So:

```
(defmacro foo ()
  (if <compile-time-condition>
      `(setq ...)
      `(setq ...)))

(foo)
```

Caveat: you can only conditionalise on things you know at compile time: your example of dispatching on UID might not do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

tfb's answer is usually the better option, but for one-off cases, you might prefer to do

```
(if (eval-when-compile (my-test))
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.gitconfig\\'" . A-mode))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.gitconfig\\'" . B-mode)))
```

which can even be rewritten to

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist 
             `("\\.gitconfig\\'"
             . ,(if (eval-when-compile (my-test)) 'A-mode 'B-mode)))
```

This relies on the compiler optimization to turn `(if <constant> a b)` into just `a` or `b` according to the constant.